# Простой запрос для того чтобы получить погоду

Tags: javascript, json, api, weather

Я начинающий и экспериментирую. Работаю с погодным API. Отправляю запрос на [сайт](http://openweathermap.org) чтобы получить информацию о погоде.

Подскажите почему **не выводится ничего в консоли** и все ли я делаю правильно?

```js
var newRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
newRequest.open("GET","http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22");

newRequest.onload = () => {
 var ourWeather = JSON.parse(newRequest.responseText);
 console.log(ourWeather);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
 <h1>JSON and AJAX</h1>
 <button id="btn">Fetch info for 3 new animals</button>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы забыли, собственно, [послать запрос](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send)

```js
var newRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

newRequest.open("GET",
"http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22");

newRequest.onload = () => {
    var ourWeather = JSON.parse(newRequest.responseText);
    console.log(ourWeather);
}

newRequest.onerror = err => console.error('Ошибка');

newRequest.send();
```

Кроме того этот сайт не даст свои страницы подгрузить через AJAX, потому что [CORS](https://habrahabr.ru/company/pentestit/blog/337146/)